# Hidden Space in URL

Tags: url, redirect, spaces, http-redirect

When I go to http://sweatingthebigstuff.com/lending-club-loans-to-avoid/, I get a 404 page. But when I hit backspace twice, it deletes the `/` but not the `d` so there's a hidden space there. Once I delete it, it works.

How is there a hidden space in my URL and can I do something to detect and delete it in the `.htaccess` file? Otherwise every redirection I add has to be one of each.

***EDIT:***

Here's what I think may be relevant from the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sweatingthebigstuff.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/(.+)$ /$1
```

It actually looks like this: `http://sweatingthebigstuff.com%E2%80%8B/lending-club-loans-to-avoid%E2%80%8B/`

Comment: Need to see your .htaccess file.

Comment: Right now, it's redirecting my browser to http://www.sweatingthebigstuff.com/lending-club-loans-avoid/

Comment: Why is there a hidden space in your URL in the first place?

Comment: that's what i'm trying to figure out. I was doing some copy and pasting and realized it was there. But had no idea how it got there and I want them all removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: That put two slashes on everything (or on everything that already had one slash).

Comment: @Daniel The extra slash is coming from the `/` after `$1`

Comment: i deleted the /, but it didn't fix the issue, when i copied and pasted the code i had, it still went to 404

Comment: @Daniel what do you mean by the code you had? Is this code other than in your .htaccess file?

Comment: I meant the URL that had the hidden space in it.